# Ajax, conditional rendering and backing beans

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I am trying to display a page where the user, by the appropriate selection using a radio button, sees either a textbox or a combo box. This is relatively easy and I managed to do that by the following code:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="selection" value="#{inputMethod.choice}">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{inputMethod.TEXT}" itemLabel="textbox"/>
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{inputMethod.COMBO}" itemLabel="combobox" />
  <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="@form" />
 </h:selectOneRadio>
<h:panelGroup id="Textbox" rendered="#{inputMethod.choice==inputMethod.TEXT}">
  <h:outputLabel>Textbox:</h:outputLabel>
  <h:inputText value="#{myBean.somevalue}" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup id="Combobox" rendered="#{inputMethod.choice==inputMethod.COMBO}"> 
  <h:outputLabel Combobox:/>
  <h:selectManyListbox id="CommunityListbox" value="#{myBean.choices}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.selections}" var="u" itemValue="#{u.id}" itemLabel="#{u.name}"/>
   </h:selectManyListbox>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

The problem I have is that the setter for the combo box is never called.
In fact, the setter is only called for the component that is rendered by default (in this case whenever `inputMethod.choice==inputMethod.TEXT`). If I remove the conditional rendering, all setters are called as one would expect.

Any ideas or answers will be greatly appreciated!

PS: I am using jsf2.0, Glassfish 3.1, Netbeans 7.0 (in case this is of any importance)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that `#{inputMethod.choice}` evaluates exactly the same during the request of processing the form submit as it did during the request of displaying the form. Easiest is to put the bean in the view scope or to move the initialization logic into the (post)constructor of the request scoped bean.